# Múltiplo de 10 mais próximo a uma soma

Tags: python, python-2.7, matemática

```
def multiplo(x):

    somamulti= somaImpares(x) + somaPares(x)

    if somamulti/10==0:
        return somamulti/10
    else:
        return
```

Nesta função que eu fiz o que acontece é o seguinte: o `somamulti` soma 2 valores, neste caso pode ser 120 + 31 = 151 e a minha função primeiro vai testar se este valor é múltiplo de 10, e, caso fosse, dava-me esse resultado. caso contrário iria me devolver o mais próximo múltiplo de 10 maior ou igual à soma dos dois valores acima, neste caso iria me devolver 160.

O que eu não sei é como chego a esse valor 160, ou seja, não consigo fazer a ultima parte do `else`.

Comment: Não sei se entendi o seu problema, acho que o que você deseja é só só isto: `return somamulti / 10 + 1) * 10` http://ideone.com/tNoe4r Tem algum problema nisto? Resolve o que você quer?

Comment: Não me parece ser o caso de if .. else. Como o @bigown mencionou, compensa retornar o valor arredondado sem fazer nenhum teste. Uma linha só de código basta: `return somamulti - ( somamulti % 10 )` serviria bem se fosse arredondado pra baixo, com ajustes pode arredondar pra cima;

Comment: @Bacco isso iria me dar 150 e eu quero o multiplo de 10 superior a 151, ou seja, 160.

Comment: Neste caso a linha de codigo que o @bigown me forneceu dá certo! Obrigada! :)

Comment: @bigown poste um completo como resposta, acho que é o caso.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Ceil(,-1) não rola ?

Answer (score 4):

Uma versão parecida com a da pergunta, mas usando módulo:

(ainda prefiro a solução puramente matemática)

```
def multiplo(x):

    somamulti= somaImpares(x) + somaPares(x)

    if somamulti % 10 == 0:
        return somamulti
    else:
        return somamulti + 10 - ( somamulti % 10 )
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/AXHPeI)**.

### Versão sem if:

```
def multiplo( x ):
    somamulti = somaImpares( x ) + somaPares( x )
    return somamulti + 9 - ( somamulti + 9 ) % 10
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/tNoe4r)**.

Comment: isso continua a dar 150 :/

Comment: Pus os links no IDEONE pras 2 versões, me parece correto, mas se algo não estiver como o esperado, avise. De qualquer forma, é a mesma solução do @bigown, só postei como exemplo de uso do operador de módulo/resto (`%`).

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa usar o `if` neste caso, dá para resolver com pura matemática. Precisa garantir que passe para a próxima dezena, então somos 9 ao número encontrado. Dividimos por 10 para perder a unidade e ficar só à partir da dezena como algo relevante. Multiplicamos por 10 para votar à escala anterior. Isto só funciona para inteiros que parece ser o caso

Ficaria assim:

```
def multiplo():
    somamulti = somaImpares(x) + somaPares(x)
    return (somamulti + 9) / 10 * 10
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9B1OeQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uqfmtkdb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Math/Multiple.py).

No seu exemplo 151 + 9 dá 160, dividindo por 10 dá 16 e multiplicando por 10 dá 160.

Se pegar 153 somando com 9 dá 162, dividindo por 10 dá 16 já que inteiro não pode ter casa decimal que é descartada e multiplicando por 10 dá 160.

Comment: isso dá certo sim, mas e se o valor fosse outro sem sem 151? já nao ia dar certo... e eu quero isso para qualquer valor

Comment: Mostre um valor que não dá certo. Eu editei o código no ideone para mostrar de 150 à 160, todas dão certo. A não ser que você esteja dizendo que se achar 150 então deveria ir para 160. Aí é só mudar o 9 p/ o 10, mas não parece que seja o que você deseja.

Comment: ah tem razão, dá certo noutros valores também, só nao consigo perceber é porque somamos 9 ao somamulti

Comment: Como você vai para a próxima dezena garantidamente? Em tese teria que somar 10. Mas se momar 10 dá problema quando você já está na próxima dezena. Ou seja se tem 150 e somar 10, vai para 160 e eu entendi que isto está errado, quando está no 150 já está na dezena que você quer. Certo? Então soma 9 para não acontecer isto. Se somar 10, quando você tiver 150, vai para 160. Isto está certo? Acho que não, mas se estiver mude de 9 para 10. E me avise.

Comment: sim sim, se tiver 150 já não é suposto fazer nada porque já é um multiplo de 10. mas agora já percebi, obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Esse é um problema de quociente e resto

```py
def multiplo():
    somamulti = somaImpares(x) + somaPares(x)
    quociente, resto = somamulti // 10, somamulti % 10
    return 10 * (quociente + (resto != 0))
```